# Dynamic Linq query In Clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have list of Customer in `List<Customer>` customerList
When I am using IsIn in dynamic query it gives me error : "No applicable method 'IsIn' exists in type 'CityCategory'"

```
customerList.AsQueryable().Where("CityCategory.IsIn(\"Metro\",\"A\")").ToList()
```

If I execute this query without dynamic linq it's run

```
customerList.Where(x => x.CityCategory.IsIn(new object[] { "Metro", "A" }));
```

Please tell me which method I have to use in dynamic linq string query.

Comment: Can you show your definition of Customerm and specifically the `IsIn` method so I can suggest an alternative. Dynamic LINQ is not smart enough to allow arbitrary method calls.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
var myList = new object[] { "Metro", "A" };

var result = customerList.Where(x => myList.Contains(x.CityCategory));
```

**Contains** will act as a **in** operator.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP has shown almost identical code to this which they say is running.

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, But I have to use dynamic linq query with string, Please see the link http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: @mayur,  IsIn isn't a method. ehsan's syntax is correct. What is it that you expect IsIn to accomplish?

Comment: It's my project requirement

Comment: @daniel, OP says _specifically_ that the code isn't running. and shows the error it produces.

Comment: See this link please, I want to do same : http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/09/18/dynamic-string-based-queries-in-linq.aspx

Comment: I want to pass string in where() like : where("myCondition")

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I suggest you read the question (and the OP's clarifying comments to this answer). The *dynamic* query is not working.

Comment: Then use in isin is no operator